# How to reuse an Angular component injecting different data?

Tags: angular, inject

I'm struggling how to reuse a component with injecting different data?

I have a customer component containing his data and shipping data linked to the customer. I want buttons to approve the customer and the shipping data.

I have a dialogcomponent with a form where I inject the customer data. I'm struggling how I can reuse that component but injecting the shipping data.

My customer component html contains a button to approve the customer:

```
<button *ngIf="canCustomerServiceApprove && showSingleCustServiceApprove" mat-raised-button (click)="customerServiceApprove(customer)" color="primary">{{'customers.management.CustomerServiceApproval' | translate}}</button>
```

This calls the method to open the dialogcomponent:

```
 private customerServiceApprove(customer?: Customer) {
    this.sourceCustomer = customer;

    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CustomerServiceApprovalDialogComponent,
        {
            panelClass: 'mat-dialog-lg',
            data: { customer: customer }
        });

}
```

Further down I have a list of shippings with their own buttons to approve the  shippings:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let shipping" fxFlex="140px">
   <button *ngIf="canCustomerServiceApprove" mat-icon-button matTooltip="{{'shippings.management.CustServApprove' | translate}}" (click)="CustServApproval(shipping)"><mat-icon>gavel</mat-icon>
   </button>
</mat-cell>
```

For now that button has a separate method:

```
private CustServApproval(shipping?: Shipping) {
    this.sourceShipping = shipping;
    alert("should open the approvaldialog for shipping id: " + this.sourceShipping.id);

}
```

The dialogcomponent gets the customer injected but cannot inject the shipping data. I get an error on the shipData, normal to me as he only gets a customer and not the shipping.

```
export class CustomerServiceApprovalDialogComponent {
@ViewChild('form')
private form: NgForm;


constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CustomerServiceApprovalDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { customer: Customer },
   // @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public shipData: { shipping: Shipping },
```

The dialogcomponent html file contains the form with a save button. I would like to show a title depending either on the customer, either on the shipping and when saving either saving with the customer id either with the shipping id.

For now I have an approve button that saves it based on the customerId:

`<button mat-raised-button (click)="save(1, data.customer.id )" color="primary">Approve</button>`

So I don't know how to inject data depending on what the component receives and for the save button depending on the received data, something like this:

```
`<button *ngIf="if customer; then type=1 id=customerid else type=2 id=shippingid mat-raised-button (click)="save(type, id )" color="primary">Approve</button>`
```

I hope it is clear?

Answer (score 0):

I used a pub/sub design pattern on my last project for some components. Not sure if this can help you, as it's very generic. But if you just create, follow, and enforce an architecture then you should be good. As a note, you could essentially do the same thing with maybe a flux/redux/mobx pattern

In the ngInit() lifecycle method of an Angular component, you can make a generic subscription method like:

Call a messaging service in your constructor:

```
constructor(private appMessagingService: AppMessaging) { }
```

ngOnInit() lifecycle method

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.sub = this.appMessagingService.getComp1Message()
                         .takeWhile(() => this.alive) //alive is just a boolean variable
                         .subscribe(message => { 
                             this.message = message; 
  });
}
```

Dont forget to clean up your observables in ngDestroy() method:

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
    this.alive = false;
}
```

Have an app-wide messaging service which has your basic send, get, and clear messages..

AppMessaging.service.ts:

```
sendComp1Message(message) {
    this.message.next(message);
}

getComp1Message(): Observable<any> {
    return this.message.asObservable();
}

clearComp1Message() {
    this.message.next();
}
```

Huge shout out to [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) guy, he has some great resources and inspired me to use this simple solution. Simple is key IMO Good luck!